# AWS Greengrass daemon failed to start in Amazon Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am trying to setup AWS Greengrass core on Amazon Linux with respect to the documentation(followed all the prerequisites) of AWS(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/start-core.html).

I am getting the below error on starting the Greengrass core daemon

```
 ./greengrassd start
Setting up greengrass daemon
Validating execution environment
Found cgroup subsystem: cpuset
Found cgroup subsystem: cpu
Found cgroup subsystem: cpuacct
Found cgroup subsystem: blkio
Found cgroup subsystem: memory
Found cgroup subsystem: devices
Found cgroup subsystem: freezer
Found cgroup subsystem: net_cls
Found cgroup subsystem: perf_event
Found cgroup subsystem: net_prio
Found cgroup subsystem: hugetlb
Found cgroup subsystem: pids

Starting greengrass daemon
Greengrass daemon 23933 failed to start
Failed to create overlay fs for container rootfs no such file or directory
```

I could not find any troubleshooting method for this and I am stuck in the middle of the process. It would be more helpful If any of you solved for me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the `./greengrassd start` command using `sudo` ?

When I omit `sudo` I can an error that says this command needs to be run with using `sudo` e.g.

`sudo ./greengrassd start`